# Square number sequence in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, sequence

I'm new to python and I am trying to make a code to print all the square numbers until the square of the desired value entered by the user.

```
    n = raw_input("Enter number")

    a = 1

    while a < n:
            a = 1
            print(a*a)
            a += 1
            if a > n:
            break
```

When I run this code it infinitely prints "1" ... I'm guessing that the value of `a` does not increase by `+=` so it's `a=1` forever. How do I fix this?

Comment: you need to convert the input you store in n into a number before comparing it to a.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some problems. First, your input (what `raw_input()` returns) is a **string**, so you must **convert it to integer**:

```
n = int(raw_input(...))
```

Second, you are setting `a = 1` each iteration, so, since the loop condition is `a < n`, the loop will run forever ( if `n > 1`). You should delete the line

```
a = 1
```

Finally, it's not necesary to check if `a > n`, because the **loop condition** will handle it:

```
while a < n:
    print a * a
    a += 1

    # 'if' is not necessary
```

Comment: Wow it worked xD thanks a lot.. so now i know not to set a=1 ... ty again

Answer (score 1):

There is a small error in your code:

```
while a < n:
    a=1            # `a` is always 1 :)
    print a*a
    a += 1
    if a > n:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the value of `a` back to `1` on every iteration of the loop, so every time it checks against `n`, the value is `2`. Remove the `a=1` line.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, your specific problem is resetting `a` each time you loop. A much more Pythonic approach to this is the `for` loop:

```
for a in range(1, n):
    print(a ** 2)
```

This means you don't have to manually increment `a` or decide when to `break` or otherwise exit a `while` loop, and is generally less prone to mistakes like resetting `a`.

Also, note that `raw_input` returns a string, you need to make it into an `int`:

```
n = int(raw_input("Enter number: "))
```

Answer (score 1):

an even better idea is to make a simple function

```
def do_square(x):
    return x*x
```

then just run a list comprehension on it

```
n = int(raw_input("Enter #:")) #this is your problem with the original code
#notice we made it into an integer
squares = [do_square(i) for i in range(1,n+1)]
```

this is a more pythonic way to do what you are trying to do
you really want to use functions to define functional blocks that are easy to digest and potentially can be reused

you can extend this concept and create a function to get input from the user and do some validation on it

```
def get_user_int():
    #a function to make sure the user enters an integer > 0
    while True:
         try:
            n = int(raw_input("Enter a number greater than zero:"))
         except TypeError:
            print "Error!! expecting a number!"
            continue;
         if n > 0: 
            return n
         print "Error: Expecting a number greater than zero!"
```

and then you can build your input right into your list

```
 squares = [do_square(i) for i in range(1,get_user_int()+1)]
```

and really `do_square` is such a simple function we could easily just do it in our loop

```
squares = [x*x for x in range(1,get_user_int())]
```

Comment: I was trying to go without a function but yep i tried it :) works great :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first line in your loop sets's `a` to one on every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You assign a=1 inside the loop. That means it's overwriting the `a+=1`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
n = eval(raw_input("Enter number"))

a=1

while a < n:            
        print a*a
        a += 1
```

The issue here is that the value of a gets overridden every time you enter in the loop

Comment: Don't forget that if you realize after posting that another answer (that's better or the same) has already been posted, there's no cost to deleting your post in order to avoid cluttering questions with answers that don't add anything.

Comment: yes i deleted the a=1 in the loop plus i HAD to make the raw_input into int(raw_input( cuz i just understood that it needs to take the integer value and not the string =D thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the condition of the while loop, to print squares of numbers upto a limiting value, try this..

```
def powers(x):
    n=1
    while((n**2)<=x):
        print(n**2, end =' ')
        n +=1
```